# svn:externals for single file does not work

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I have set up the svn:externals to get single file from repository, like so:

```
/svn/BuildScripts/build.xml build.xml
```

and when I run svn up I get

```
Fetching external item into 'build.xml'
svn: warning: Repository UUID '2b850f39-0897-4e1c-b099-849a384f3d4c' doesn't match expected UUID 'd4f4866e-acd6-4900-9c2e-0614c950fc97'
```

however build.xml does not appear in the checkout directory. Any idea what might be wrong?
By the way I am using svn 1.6.18 (r1303927)

Answer (score 1):

You can see problem in plain English:

For some reason `/svn/BuildScripts/build.xml` exist in repository with UUID `2b850f39-0897-4e1c-b099-849a384f3d4c`, which is **not the same** as `d4f4866e-acd6-4900-9c2e-0614c950fc97`, but file-based extenals must exist on the same repo (i.e share common UUID)

Test UUID (and other info) of /svn/BuildScripts/build.xml with `svn info`, show here `svn pl` for mount-point of externals (idrectory, for which you added externals definition), bind externals source to repo, using ^-syntax in URL

Comment: I kind of thought so, though it does not make much sense to me having an external in the same repository - I would the have this file twice, first from the repo, and then from externals, correct?

Comment: @BolekTekielski - no, repository storage for files may (have) be outside the usual trunk, thus in WC you'll get only one instance. And file-level externals are needed, when and if you want to link to **file from external repo** - it this case you'll svn:external to **parent dir** in DST repo (outside working subtree) and mount only needed files to final destination. Show you repository here, I'll try to identify problem

Comment: my setup is as follows: https://myrepo/svn/src and https://myrepo/svn/BuildScripts, myrepo being the same URL in both cases. Now I would like to pull different files from BuildScripts repo and put hem in different subfolders in src repo. Is it sufficient for you to help me nail down the problem?